# How to merge multiple CAShapeLayers into one in swift

Tags: ios, swift, scale, cashapelayer

I've got multiple bezier paths which are incorporated into CAShapeLayers for animation purposes. I need to know if it is possible to merge all of the layers into one collection object so that I can scale it in the following way:

```
shapes.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1)
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: If you apply the transform to the layers' super layer, does it apply the transfer to them all?

Comment: I don't know, I'll have a try

Comment: If the shapes have the same properties (stroke width, fill color, line caps etc.) you can construct a single path. Another solution is applying the transform to each layer.